# how to scrape all data with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrape all destination names from https://www.azamara.com/int/find-a-journey#sort=date-asc using selenium but when i run my script it is only takes 12 names.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
url = 'https://www.azamara.com/int/find-a-journey#sort=date-asc'
driver.get(url)
destinations =[]

for i in range(1,1000,1) :
  path = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[{}]/div[3]/div/div[1]'.format(i)
         
     
  destination = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(path)
  destinations.append(destination)

cleaned = [x for x in destinations if x != []]

for c in cleaned :
  print(c[0].text)
```

It prints always the following data and not all data :

```
7-Night Greece Intensive Voyage
7-Nigh Greece Intensive Voyage
7-Night Greece Intensive Voyage
7-Night Greece Intensive Voyage
7-Night Greece Intensive Voyage
11-Night Greece Intensive Voyage
7-Night Classic Mediterranean Voyage
10-Night Italy Intensive Voyage
12-Night Greece Intensive Voyage
11-Night Aegean Pursuit Voyage
9-Night Amalfi & Dalmation Coasts Voyage
10-Night Israel Intensive Voyage
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Did you see there is a "load more itineraries" button there?

Comment: I see there is a `LOAD more Itineraries ` do you want to keep on clicking that and scrape the new names ?

Comment: i want to scrape all data but i dont know why it is scraping only those !!!!!

Comment: Because you need to click on load more itineraries and scrape.. continue till you are done !